# Analytics has encountered an unexpected condition and cannot fulfill your request

Tags: google-analytics

I just signed up for google analytics for my website yesterday. It was working fine until today. However, after a while, it is popping up this error:

```
Internal error. Please try again later.Analytics has encountered an unexpected condition and cannot fulfill your request.
```

Not sure what this error is and how to solve it.. Need some guidance.

Comment: This appears to be an issue at Google.

Comment: Having this issue too, it's Google.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Disable AdBlock in your browser, and you'll be able to access your reports again.

Edit: Another fix. When you access your GA page, you'll see a URL like this:

```
https://ads.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#home/aBunchOfNumbersAndLetters/
```

Change the "ads" to "www":

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#home/aBunchOfNumbersAndLetters/
```

That "ads" in the URL is triggering misbehavior by AdBlock

Comment: Google Analytics has changed the URL, so it no longer triggers AdBlock. Problem solved, without any user intervention required.

Comment: No it still gets blocked because of Ad Block

Comment: I am not getting the error in any browser, with AdBlock active. Google has changed the URL again, so that it's https://analytics.google.com/analytics (etc.). That doesn't trigger AdBlock. Make sure you haven't bookmarked the old "ads" URL.

Comment: Did you try uBlock ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en

Comment: Can confirm as of 23/05/16 that AdBlock, uBlock Origin et al still cause this issue with Google Analytics.

Comment: If you're using the correct URL, no blocking will occur. I'm not seeing it at all.

Comment: Makes no difference with ad blocker active or disabled.

Comment: This problem went away over two years ago, when Google changed the URL for Analytics, so I don't know what you're even referring to.

Comment: Still doesnt work with ublock or adblock on even if disabling for analytics.google.com

Answer (score 20):

Another extension that causes Analytics to stop working is uBlock Origin.
If you disable that extension when you are on the analytics site, it starts working again.

Comment: Not the case anymore (in my experience). I see the error, disabled the uBlock Origin plugin, and it still shows.

Comment: in that case its probably another adblocker or security / privacy extension or adblocking "hosts file" that is causing it

Answer (score 5):

Disabling AdBlock Plus on analytics.google.com page worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is the adblocker, you can try **whitelisting** the Analytics website. For uBlock Origin you need to go to the extension settings, select the tab **Whitelist**, and then add the Google Analytics link (analytics.google.com) to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods whichever gets you to success:

1. Try disabling your AdBlock extension (uBlock or AbBlocker or the one you have added).
2. Try whitelisting the Analytics Page on your AdBlock extension and see if it might help.
3. If the above two are not working, try removing the AdBlock from the chrome extensions temporarily and check if something happens or
   not.
4. If still, something doesn't go right then, before step 3, check the id of the Adblock extension, remove it and then go to your
   device, find
   C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data\Default\Extensions folder.
   Inside this, If you find any folder with a name similar to your chrome extension id, delete it. This will surely
   help.

Please add to it if anyone finds any new way to deal with this problem